# Can anyone suggest me any tools using which I can schedule my UI testing, so that it automatically starts testing at a given interval of time

Tags: selenium, automation, scheduled-tasks, ui-automation, scheduling

I want to write a scheduler inside my java code that schedules my UI test cases and it automatically starts testing at the given time. Suggestion needed for plugins or tools.

Comment: Why don't you try to use jenkins?? Hope following refered link can help
[automationstepbystep.com/jenkins](https://automationstepbystep.com/jenkins)

Answer (score 1):

There are different options, depending on what you're trying to achieve.

1. If you want to schedule the next execution purely from Java - consider [Quartz Job Scheduling Library](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org)
2. Alternatively you can use underlying operating system task scheduling mechanisms, to wit:

   - Windows: [Task Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page)
   - Linux: [crontab](https://linuxconfig.org/linux-crontab-reference-guide)
   - MacOS: [launchd](https://www.maketecheasier.com/use-launchd-run-scripts-on-schedule-macos/)
3. And last but not the least, you can put your tests under [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) tool orchestration like:

   - [Jenkins](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/jenkins-pipeline-selenium/)
   - [Buildbot](http://mariangemarcano.blogspot.com/2012/08/buildbot-part-ii-running-automated.html)
   - [CruiseControl](https://hedleyproctor.com/2011/07/automating-selenium-testing-with-testng-ant-and-cruisecontrol/)